# Screen goes blank when moving camera

Tags: three.js, camera, rendering, renderer

I'm attempting to create something in `three.js` and I'm moderately successful in building the geometry from text files. To start off, I manage to get a game level file to display complete with textures. Then I try to load the models from that game and suddenly the screen would go blank as soon as I try to move around. I can look around, but moving kills the screen.

I then remove the part about loading the models, but still keep their position in memory, and the same thing happens.

After taking a good look, it turns out that after I set the camera's position to the player's position, then try to move, that is when the screen goes blank.

Some of the code snippet involving how the camera is set up:

```
var getPlayers = document.createElement("select");
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.001, 10000 );
var LOADING_COMPLETE = false;
```

A whole bunch of loading functions follow...

```
function CompleteTheLoading()
{
    document.getElementById("mainmenu").innerHTML = "<b>Jump to </b>";
    document.getElementById("mainmenu").appendChild(getPlayers);
    yawObject.position.x = jklthings[getPlayers.value][3];
    yawObject.position.y = jklthings[getPlayers.value][4];
    yawObject.position.z = jklthings[getPlayers.value][5];
    yawObject.rotation.z = jklthings[getPlayers.value][7]*Math.PI/180;
    LOADING_COMPLETE = true;
    animate();
}
getPlayers.onchange = function()
{
    velocity.x = 0;
    velocity.y = 0;
    velocity.z = 0;
    yawObject.position.x = jklthings[getPlayers.value][3];
    yawObject.position.y = jklthings[getPlayers.value][4];
    yawObject.position.z = jklthings[getPlayers.value][5];
    yawObject.rotation.z = jklthings[getPlayers.value][7]*Math.PI/180;
    if (document.activeElement != document.body) document.activeElement.blur();
}


var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
var mouseK = 0;
var havePointerLock = 'pointerLockElement' in document ||
    'mozPointerLockElement' in document ||
    'webkitPointerLockElement' in document;
var moveForward = false;
var moveBackward = false;
var moveLeft = false;
var moveRight = false;
var canJump = false;
var prevTime = performance.now();
var velocity = new THREE.Vector3();
var direction = new THREE.Vector3();

var onKeyDown = function ( event ) {
    switch ( event.keyCode ) {
        case 38: // up
        case 87: // w
            moveForward = true;
            break;
        case 37: // left
        case 65: // a
            moveLeft = true;
            break;
        case 40: // down
        case 83: // s
            moveBackward = true;
            break;
        case 39: // right
        case 68: // d
            moveRight = true;
            break;
    }
};
var onKeyUp = function ( event ) {
    switch( event.keyCode ) {
        case 38: // up
        case 87: // w
            moveForward = false;
            break;
        case 37: // left
        case 65: // a
            moveLeft = false;
            break;
        case 40: // down
        case 83: // s
            moveBackward = false;
            break;
        case 39: // right
        case 68: // d
            moveRight = false;
            break;
        case 78: // n
            if(getPlayers.selectedIndex==getPlayers.length-1)
                getPlayers.selectedIndex=0;
            else
                getPlayers.selectedIndex=getPlayers.selectedIndex+1;
            getPlayers.onchange();
            break;
        case 80: // p
            if(getPlayers.selectedIndex==0)
                getPlayers.selectedIndex=getPlayers.length-1;
            else
                getPlayers.selectedIndex=getPlayers.selectedIndex-1;
            getPlayers.onchange();
            break;
        case 13: // Enter
            getPlayers.onchange();
            break;
    }
};
document.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );
document.addEventListener( 'keyup', onKeyUp, false );

var pitchObject = new THREE.Object3D();
pitchObject.add( camera );
var yawObject = new THREE.Object3D();
yawObject.add( pitchObject );
scene.add(yawObject);
var PI_2 = Math.PI / 2;
camera.rotation.x = 90*Math.PI/180;

function animate()
{
    var time = performance.now();
    var delta = ( time - prevTime ) / 1000;
    velocity.x -= velocity.x * 1.0 * delta;
    velocity.y -= velocity.y * 1.0 * delta;
    velocity.z -= velocity.z * 1.0 * delta;
    direction.z = Number( moveForward ) - Number( moveBackward );
    direction.x = Number( moveLeft ) - Number( moveRight );
    direction.normalize(); // this ensures consistent movements in all directions
    if ( moveForward || moveBackward )
    {
        velocity.y -= direction.z * 1.0 * -delta;
        velocity.z -= direction.z * pitchObject.rotation.x * 1.0 * -delta;;
    }
    if ( moveLeft || moveRight )
        velocity.x -= direction.x * 1.0 * delta;
    if(mouseK==1)
    {

        yawObject.rotation.z -= mouseX * 0.01;
        pitchObject.rotation.x -= mouseY * 0.01;
        pitchObject.rotation.x = Math.max( - PI_2, Math.min( PI_2, pitchObject.rotation.x ) );
    }
    yawObject.translateX( velocity.x * delta );
    yawObject.translateY( velocity.y * delta );
    yawObject.translateZ( velocity.z * delta );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    prevTime = time;
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}
function mouseMovement(e)
{
    mouseX = e.movementX || e.mozMovementX || e.webkitMovementX || 0;
    mouseY = e.movementY || e.mozMovementY || e.webkitMovementY || 0;
}

renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', function()
{
    if(LOADING_COMPLETE==true)
    {
        mouseK = 1;
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMovement, false);
    }
},false);
renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'mouseup', function()
{
    // Ask the browser to release the pointer
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMovement, false);
    mouseX = 0;
    mouseY = 0;
    mouseK = 0;
},false);
```

Now, you are probably noticing that the camera is set at an angle. This is due to that the game is `Z-up` while `three.js` is `Y-up`. Rotating and recalculating the whole level is no fun, so I just jumble the camera instead.

Also, for the most part when I change `getPlayers` it still renders, but after I move I can't get it back even after `getPlayers`.

Making snippet, and oddly enough that works when setting the position of the `yawObject`. Except it won't run in this snippet. But here it is anyways.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script>
var LOADING_COMPLETE=true;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.001, 10000 );

// A whole lot of Loading Functions removed...
// All that remains is three's Materials Example:
var geometry = new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry( 10, 3, 100, 16 );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({}) );
scene.add( mesh );

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
var mouseK = 0;
var havePointerLock = 'pointerLockElement' in document ||
 'mozPointerLockElement' in document ||
 'webkitPointerLockElement' in document;
var moveForward = false;
var moveBackward = false;
var moveLeft = false;
var moveRight = false;
var canJump = false;
var prevTime = performance.now();
var velocity = new THREE.Vector3();
var direction = new THREE.Vector3();

var onKeyDown = function ( event ) {
 switch ( event.keyCode ) {
  case 38: // up
  case 87: // w
   moveForward = true;
   break;
  case 37: // left
  case 65: // a
   moveLeft = true;
   break;
  case 40: // down
  case 83: // s
   moveBackward = true;
   break;
  case 39: // right
  case 68: // d
   moveRight = true;
   break;
 }
};
var onKeyUp = function ( event ) {
 switch( event.keyCode ) {
  case 38: // up
  case 87: // w
   moveForward = false;
   break;
  case 37: // left
  case 65: // a
   moveLeft = false;
   break;
  case 40: // down
  case 83: // s
   moveBackward = false;
   break;
  case 39: // right
  case 68: // d
   moveRight = false;
   break;
  case 78: // n
   if(getPlayers.selectedIndex==getPlayers.length-1)
    getPlayers.selectedIndex=0;
   else
    getPlayers.selectedIndex=getPlayers.selectedIndex+1;
   getPlayers.onchange();
   break;
  case 80: // p
   if(getPlayers.selectedIndex==0)
    getPlayers.selectedIndex=getPlayers.length-1;
   else
    getPlayers.selectedIndex=getPlayers.selectedIndex-1;
   getPlayers.onchange();
   break;
  case 13: // Enter
   getPlayers.onchange();
   break;
 }
};
document.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );
document.addEventListener( 'keyup', onKeyUp, false );

var pitchObject = new THREE.Object3D();
pitchObject.add( camera );
var yawObject = new THREE.Object3D();
yawObject.add( pitchObject );
scene.add(yawObject);
var PI_2 = Math.PI / 2;
camera.rotation.x = 90*Math.PI/180;

 yawObject.position.x = 10.7;
 yawObject.position.y = 20.2;
 yawObject.position.z = 0;
 yawObject.rotation.z = 135*Math.PI/180;

animate();

function animate()
{
 var time = performance.now();
 var delta = ( time - prevTime ) / 1000;
 velocity.x -= velocity.x * 1.0 * delta;
 velocity.y -= velocity.y * 1.0 * delta;
 velocity.z -= velocity.z * 1.0 * delta;
 direction.z = Number( moveForward ) - Number( moveBackward );
 direction.x = Number( moveLeft ) - Number( moveRight );
 direction.normalize(); // this ensures consistent movements in all directions
 if ( moveForward || moveBackward )
 {
  velocity.y -= direction.z * 1.0 * -delta;
  velocity.z -= direction.z * pitchObject.rotation.x * 1.0 * -delta;;
 }
 if ( moveLeft || moveRight )
  velocity.x -= direction.x * 1.0 * delta;
 if(mouseK==1)
 {

  yawObject.rotation.z -= mouseX * 0.01;
  pitchObject.rotation.x -= mouseY * 0.01;
  pitchObject.rotation.x = Math.max( - PI_2, Math.min( PI_2, pitchObject.rotation.x ) );
 }
 yawObject.translateX( velocity.x * delta );
 yawObject.translateY( velocity.y * delta );
 yawObject.translateZ( velocity.z * delta );
 renderer.render( scene, camera );
 prevTime = time;
 requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}
function mouseMovement(e)
{
 mouseX = e.movementX || e.mozMovementX || e.webkitMovementX || 0;
 mouseY = e.movementY || e.mozMovementY || e.webkitMovementY || 0;
}

renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', function()
{
 if(LOADING_COMPLETE==true)
 {
  mouseK = 1;
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMovement, false);
 }
},false);
renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'mouseup', function()
{
 document.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMovement, false);
 mouseX = 0;
 mouseY = 0;
 mouseK = 0;
},false);

window.onresize = function()
{
 camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
Following Jim's advice, I've reconstructed the code bit by bit, keeping the "teleportation" part, and calling it to some arbitrary numbers. Everything seems to work fine, even after the final touches of loading `jklthings`. As soon as I change the arbitrary numbers to the coordinates of the `jklthings` that represent a player, it breaks like above.

Using a `console.log(jklthings[getPlayers.value][3] + "\t" + jklthings[getPlayers.value][4] + "\t" + jklthings[getPlayers.value][5] + "\t" + jklthings[getPlayers.value][7]*Math.PI/180);` I get the values `-4.9   5.9 .1  0`. Feeding these in manually, everything works.

Comment: Can you create a [`Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which exhibits the same problem? You may find your own answer along the way, and it will make debugging easier for us. Also, consider using [`Snippets`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), which will let us run the code right here in your question.

Comment: @TheJim01 I made a snippet and it ran on the server. I copied snippet into "runnable snippet" but it does not run here.

Comment: Your snippet isn't running at all because you placed your HTML in the JavaScript pane. Move all of your code to the HTML pane, and you'll be able to continue debugging.

Comment: @TheJim01 Fixed.

Comment: Are you saying you can't get the snippet to fail the same way your server code does? Or do we need to do something specific to get it to fail?

Comment: @TheJim01 The snippet isn't failing as it does on the server.

Comment: Now it's time to take baby steps. Move the snippet to your server as-is, and see if it runs. If it fails, then there's something wrong with your server. If it runs, then start adding your extra functionality to it, one piece at a time until it fails. At that point you should have a good idea of where the problem code lives.

Comment: @TheJim01 I made sure the snippet ran on my server before posting it here. Now I reconstructed the original code onto it, and all worked up until I added `jklthings` to the "teleporting coordinates". See my EDIT for details.